# How do I replace the background image of a webpage in Javascript before it's loaded?

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events

I am currently overwriting the CSS of a webgame I play to give a more pleasant user experience. The only thing that I am having difficulty with is replacing the background image correctly, as the original background image loads onto the screen before the script replaces it to a solid color. The solid color that I am replacing it with loads, but not until after the page loads.

[Here is a gif of the issue I am running into.](http://www.gfycat.com/FatherlyUnknownBee)

I have tried using document.onload, .onDomContentLoaded, .ready, etc, but for some reason none of these are working. Is there any way I can prevent the background image from loading before the script is run?

Comment: why not remove that background image itself from the css?

Answer (score 0):

`window.onload` will wait for all the resources to load.

However, it sounds like you should just add a `background-color` to the element and let the background render beneath it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the property as important? `background-color: gray !important`
I think this should prevent the image from showing up at all

Answer (score 0):

Place this in an *external* Javascript file, and make a request for it before anything else in your `head`.

```
var myImage = new Image();
myImage.src = 'your_image_here';
```

What happens is that an external Javascript file blocks the rendering of the page. And the script itself will not finish till the image has been downloaded. So there won’t be any delay when you do switch the background.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

document.style.backgroundImage="url('img.png')";

Answer (score 0):

I believe AmmarCSE is hinting at a possible answer, but the cause is unknown.

You should first review your HTML for the order in which your resources are loaded. The CSS is a loaded resource and can specify background colors and images. This will possibly explain the following:

If your CSS specifies colors/image resources, and the HTML loads the CSS resource prior to executing your document functions, you will continue to get this behavior.

---

You should review the CSS for the background image/color and change it there instead of attempting to override it with document functions.

This is an assumption of the problem. You should provide some HTML, JavaScript, and CSS in your original post to help others answer and review.

Comment: Also, you may wish to look at using a prepackaged CSS solution instead of surgery.